# Playing AVAudioPlayer causes delay

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, delay

I use AVAudioPlayer object to play an aif sound file that should go on unless the game is over. I have an ivar of AVAudioPlayer called backgroundPlayer and I set it up in viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 NSURL *backgroundURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle        
 mainBundle]pathForResource:@"bgLoop" ofType:@"aif"]];
 backgroundPlayer=[[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundURL    
                                                               error:nil] retain];
 backgroundAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops=-1;
```

}

And then I play it in viewWillAppear method:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{    
    TrafficAppDelegate *delegate=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
     if (delegate.shouldPlaySFX)
       [backgroundPlayer play];
}
```

With this all set when I push my button to push the view controller to the stack I hangs for about 2-3 seconds and only after that the view appears. If I comment the  [backgroundPlayer play] command in viewWillAppear method the delay goes away. Shouldn't I use AVAudioPlayer class for playing this kind of sounds? I mean the sound can go on for minutes, even hours.If the choose is not the issue then what can cause the delay? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this case after adding **[backgroundPlayer prepareToPlay]** in your code? I believe this will solve the delay issue.

Answer (score 0):

It happens the first time you try to play a sound. You can play short silent sound in your appdelegate to make the `AVAudioPlayer` responsive when you really need it.